# Latex table inserts new line at the end

Tags: tables, line-breaking

I am creating two tables, But somehow, there is an empty line between these two tables.

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{Properties of the magnetic Resolver}\label{tab:resvprop}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Parameter} &      \textbf{Value}\\
\hline
Maximum amplitude of the excitation voltage        &       9.0V \\
Excitation frequency  &       10kHz \\   
Number of Pole pairs          &       4 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[!htb]
\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{Properties of the Reference Encoder}\label{tab:Encprop}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Parameter} &      \textbf{Value}\\
\hline
Pulses per Revolution/ Line count      &       1024 \\
Output signals    &       Sine, Cosine \\   
Output signal amplitude          &       1.0V\\
Accuracy         &       \pm 0.0176\textdegree  \\
Power supply               &       DC 5\pm 0.5 V\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

[image]

How Can I remove the empty space between the two tables?

Comment: mostly it is from your two `center` environments, use `\centering` rather than the environment form in floats.

Comment: Also, "table" tells TeX "put this where you think best".  If you really want them next to each other, then look through https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/107497

Comment: How about `\vspace{-1em}` between the two `table` environments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The excess space is due to two factors

1. `center` adds vertical space; use `\centering` instead;
2. two consecutive floats are separated by the amount of `\floatsep`.

Here's how you can reduce it, still maintaining separate floats.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{Properties of the magnetic Resolver}\label{tab:resvprop}

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Parameter}} & \textbf{Value}\\
\hline
Maximum amplitude of the excitation voltage & \SI{9.0}{\volt} \\
Excitation frequency                        & \SI{10}{\kilo\hertz} \\
Number of Pole pairs                        & 4 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}


\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{Properties of the Reference Encoder}\label{tab:Encprop}

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Parameter}} & \textbf{Value}\\
\hline
Pulses per Revolution/Line count & 1024 \\
Output signals                   & Sine, Cosine \\   
Output signal amplitude          & \SI{1.0}{\volt} \\
Accuracy                         & \SI{\pm 0.0176}{\degree} \\
Power supply                     & DC \SI{5\pm 0.5}{\volt} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used `siunitx` in order to get correct output for the measurements with their units. I also changed the alignment of the first columns to left.

You might prefer to use a single `table` environment, though. Here I also modify the table codes for better appearance. But you can take the idea and keep the caged tables, if you prefer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}

\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
  \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{\medskipamount}
  \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{Properties of the magnetic Resolver}\label{tab:resvprop}

\begin{tabular}{@{}lc@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Parameter} & Value \\
\midrule
Maximum amplitude of the excitation voltage & \SI{9.0}{\volt} \\
Excitation frequency                        & \SI{10}{\kilo\hertz} \\
Number of Pole pairs                        & 4 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\caption{Properties of the Reference Encoder}\label{tab:Encprop}

\begin{tabular}{@{}lc@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Parameter} & Value\\
\midrule
Pulses per Revolution/Line count & 1024 \\
Output signals                   & Sine, Cosine \\   
Output signal amplitude          & \SI{1.0}{\volt} \\
Accuracy                         & \SI{\pm 0.0176}{\degree} \\
Power supply                     & DC \SI{5\pm 0.5}{\volt} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]